# using local database as a file

Tags: mysql, database

is there any database that i could use to store logs and to connect to it i don't need to create server/ open connection, i want to use the database like a file system as we simply open file using open command, i could have just used file-system but i also want to query the file. Like in MYSQL we have to use XAMPP or other hosts to connect to the database. As in case of node we can simply open a file like:

```
fs.readFile(filname,callback);
```

same thing i want to achieve but i also want to query the data.

Comment: MySQL is based on a client-server architecture. Use a database like SQLite if you need a lightweight, embedded, in-process, file-based database.

Comment: is there another lite datbase for mongodb?